How to reference tcolorbox title
The amsthm package has some really nice features regarding theorems numbering and referencing, but it lacks the visual flexibility I'm looking for. I'm looking for ways to reference my environments without amsthm.
Here's an image of what I'm looking for.

I don't know how to refer to the appropriate counter and title of the environment. Here's my current approach.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Definition environment
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{definition}[2][]{
    title=Definition~\thetcbcounter: #2,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\begin{definition}{Test}\label{def:example}
    Test
\end{definition}
\begin{definition}{Test 2}\label{def:lorem}
    lorem ipsum.
\end{definition}
I'd like to reference Definition \ref{def:example}, but it seems that the ref command always displays the section number. For instance, \ref{def:lorem} will have the same number as \ref{def:example}.

Similarly, I'd like to know if there's a way to reference the title of the definition. If I try to reference \nameref{def:example}, it'll also return the section name, instead of the tcolorbox environment title.

\end{document}

What can I do to reference my tcolorboxes?

Using \NewTcbTheorem might be easier

(Disclaimer: I wrote the package, keytheorems, used in this answer.)
You should either use tcolorbox's built-in theorems library, or you can use the package keytheorems which uses amsthm under the hood and can produce tcolorbox theorems with the tcolorbox key.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not necessary with current LaTeX
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{keytheorems}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Definition environment
\newkeytheoremstyle{defistyle}{
  tcolorbox, % or tcolorbox={<options>}
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  notefont=\bfseries,
  notebraces={}{},
  headpunct={},
  noteseparator={: },
  }
\newkeytheorem{definition}[parent=section,style=defistyle]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\begin{definition}[note=Test,label=def:example]
    Test
\end{definition}
\begin{definition}[note=Test 2,label=def:lorem]
    lorem ipsum.
\end{definition}
I'd like to reference Definition \ref{def:example}, but it seems that the ref command always displays the section number. For instance, \ref{def:lorem} will have the same number as \ref{def:example}.

Similarly, I'd like to know if there's a way to reference the title of the definition. If I try to reference \nameref{def:example}, it'll also return the section name, instead of the tcolorbox environment title.

\end{document}



I couldn't find this package in our list ... :-)

@UlrikeFischer Ha well, it's not even in texlive yet... but it is definitely incompatible
